# requestedExecutionLevel reset after using signtool.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, manifest, elevation, signtool

I'm using signtool.exe to create a digital signature for my Installer.exe, but I want the installer's manifest file to have the requestedExecutionLevel = "requireAdministrator". 
To do so I'm running a build.bat file that contains the following: steps

1. - extract the manifest:
     mt -inputresource:\Installer.exe;#1 -out:\Installer.exe.manifest
   - change the elevation from asInvoker to requireAdministrator
   - update the manifest file with the new value:
     mt.exe -nologo -manifest "\Installer.exe.manifest" -outputresource:"\Installer.exe;#1
2. sign the Installer.exe using the signtool.exe
   signtool.exe sign /f ....\Common\ /p "password" /t http://tsa.starfieldtech.com /v build\Installer.exe

First step worked smoothly, but when the digital signature is executed, the manifest file gets updated with the requestedExecutionLevel = "asInvoker".

I tried first signing and afterwords setting the requestedExecutionLevel, but that removes my digital signature.

Didn't find a similar issue.
Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I found out how to solve the problem.

When trying to run mt.exe it was failing because I didn't have the PATH set, so what I did was simply set the path localy in the batch file that is calling the extract manifest and update manifest. My batch file looks like this:

```
SETLOCAL

SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64;

CALL extractManifest.bat

CALL changeElevation.bat

CALL updateManifest.bat

CALL codeSigning.bat
```

Now it works, I have both the digital signature and the requestedExecutionLevel=requireAdministrator.